# Javascript - convert String to value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a custom password input system. Currently, the password is saved as a string. For example, I would have a password variable like this:

```
var password = "ABCDEFGH";
```

However, when using a normal textbox, and input passwords, the value us returned as a `value` object, for example `textContent.value` where textContent is a textbox. Since there are no data types in javascript unlike Java, how can I make the password, which is currently a string, into the same type as a `value` object?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you're using client-side javascript to handle passwords then this isn't going to work.

Comment: `.value` is a string not a object. Not sure if i am understanding your problem.

Comment: What? There is no such thing like a value object... String is perfectly fine for passwords.

Comment: DOM contents *(values included)* are treated as Strings, whether by assignment or when getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special type for the "value" object.

`for example textContent.value where textContent is a textbox`.

In this case, textContent.value will give you the value in that textbox but its type will be string.

**Accessing** password field:

`var password = textContent.value;`

**Assigning** password to DOM object:

`textContent.value = password;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = String(textContent.value);
```